# SQL Join not appearing

Tags: sql

hello i am having trouble with this join, can someone help? still new so thank you for the recommendations

i'm going to try to explain what i am wanting to accomplish, forgive me if i don't make sense. i have 4 tables that all have some sort of information, but cannot create a join to bring only what i need. the tables below have the data and the **bold** is what i need from them to create the output.

here is what i have

- table 1 has **name**, dept, address, type
- table 2 has name, **ID**, salary, location
- table 3 has ID, **date of work**
- table 4 has ID, name, **hr hire date**

````
select
       table1.name as name,
       table1.manager as manager,
       table2.ID,
from table1
left join table2 on table1.ID=table2.ID

JOIN (table3 INNER JOIN table4 ON table3.date = table4.hire_date) ON table1.name = table3.name ```

name         manager    ID      date hired
jack frost  cinderalla  75654   5/1/2020
tooth fairy snow white  6542    6/1/2019
````

Comment: HI, you are going to have to provide a lot more detail.  Please edit the question and show table definitions, sample data for each table, and expected output.  thanks

Comment: The problem you are trying to solve is entirely unclear.

Comment: Does table 1 have ID field or no? Your definition does not include it, but your join does.

Comment: yes table 1 has an ID field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

table name can not use as column
I think here's error

```
select
       table1.name as name,
       table2.name as manager_name,
       table3.employee_ID
from table1
left join table2 on table1.name=table2.name
left join table3 on table1.name=table3.name
JOIN (table4 INNER JOIN table5 ON table4.table4_name = table5.table5_name) as table5 ON table1.name = table5.table5_name
```